# Write to file: Constraints and Variables of Gurobi GRBModel in Java

Tags: java, gurobi

I consider some code for an integer linear program and it executes as expected (see at the end of the question). Now, I am looking for a procedure that let's me write the ILP to a file so that a human can read it, for example, in the file it should read something like in the following:

```
maximize x + y + 2 z
c0: x + 2 y + 3 z <= 4
c1: x + y >= 1
x binary
y binary
z binary
```

The exact format does not matter, I just need to be able to read it. How can I achieve this?

**The Code:**

```
import gurobi.*;

public class Mip1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

  // Create empty environment, set options, and start
  GRBEnv env = new GRBEnv(true);
  env.set("logFile", "mip1.log");
  env.start();

  // Create empty model
  GRBModel  model = new GRBModel(env);

  // Create variables
  GRBVar x = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "x");
  GRBVar y = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "y");
  GRBVar z = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "z");

  // Set objective: maximize x + y + 2 z
  GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
  expr.addTerm(1.0, x); expr.addTerm(1.0, y); expr.addTerm(2.0, z);
  model.setObjective(expr, GRB.MAXIMIZE);

  // Add constraint: x + 2 y + 3 z <= 4
  expr = new GRBLinExpr();
  expr.addTerm(1.0, x); expr.addTerm(2.0, y); expr.addTerm(3.0, z);
  model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, 4.0, "c0");

  // Add constraint: x + y >= 1
  expr = new GRBLinExpr();
  expr.addTerm(1.0, x); expr.addTerm(1.0, y);
  model.addConstr(expr, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, 1.0, "c1");

  // Optimize model
  model.optimize();

  // Dispose of model and environment
  model.dispose();
  env.dispose();

} catch (GRBException e) {
  System.out.println("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode() + ". " +
                     e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing out your model as an LP file. The LP file format is not standardized across different solvers, but in general it closely matches the format you described.

In the Gurobi Java API, we can write the model to a file using the [GRBModel.write()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/java_model_write.html) method. For example, if we add `model.write("mip1.lp");` directly before the call to `GRBModel.optimize()`, Gurobi creates the file `mip1.lp` with the following contents:

```
\ LP format - for model browsing. Use MPS format to capture full model detail.
Maximize
  x + y + 2 z
Subject To
 c0: x + 2 y + 3 z <= 4
 c1: x + y >= 1
Bounds
Binaries
 x y z
End
```

Because LP files are meant to be human-readable, Gurobi may truncate some digits when writing the file. If you want to write the model using full precision, you should use the MPS file format (which is not easily readable by humans).

You can read the file into a `GRBModel` object by using the model filename as the second argument in the [GRBModel() constructor](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/java_model2.html). E.g.:

```
GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env, "mip1.lp");
```